# How to use map and lambda in Python to clean up return statements

Tags: python-3.7

Using Python 3.7

I have a function with multiple if conditions. As each condition gets evaluated, its data gets added as a string to a variable and then the variable is returned.
Because  a variable can't be added to in the return statement, the code has gotten repetitive. This looks like a good use case for utilizing `map` with a `lambda` function, but I'm not clear on how to add to a variable in that way across multiple `if` and `for` conditions.

Here is a simplified version of the function:

```
    def querying(collection, transformers):

        new_data = ''

        if transformers and 'fields' in transformers:
            for f in transformers['fields']:

                if not 'null':

                    if transformers['fields'][0] == 'open':
                        new_data = 'state' + 'open'
                        return new_data
                    elif transformers['fields'][0] == 'closed':
                        new_data =  'state' + 'closed'
                        return new_data
                    elif transformers['fields'][0] == 'mid':
                        new_data =  'state' + 'mid'
                        return new_data
                    elif transformers['fields'][0] == 'not started':
                        new_data =  'state' + output_of_another_function()
                        return new_data
                else:
                    return
```

Doing something like

```
return new_data = 'state' + 'not started'
```

Returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

This is what I mean by being unable to add to a variable on the return line.

I realize that in this case it looks unnecessary to have the return statement return the variable `new_data` instead of just a string like `'state' + 'open'` which is of course possible to do in the return statement. However, in the function I am actually working with, there might be another function call that inputs data into `new_data`, so I want this variable returned in every statement. This is shown in the above example:

```
elif transformers['fields'][0] == 'not started':
    new_data =  'state' + output_of_another_function()
    return new_data
```

Changing that to this:

```
elif transformers['fields'][0] == 'not started':
    
    return new_data =  'state' + output_of_another_function()
```

This obviously errors with`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: _a variable can't be added to in the return statement_ That's not true. `return 'state ' + ' not started'` is legal. But there are other issues with your code.

Comment: `if not 'null':` is _always_ `False`. Ooops. The string `'null'` is "truthy" so not truthy equals "False".

Comment: Don't use `is` to test equality. Use `==`. Example: `if transformers['fields'][0] == 'open':`

Comment: What is your desired output for this function?

Comment: Thanks  for the comments! The actual function I am working with is much more complex than this so I tried to create a simple example of it just to show the concepts I'm working with. I am updating my original question for clarity now.

Comment: The "walrus" operator can help: `return (new_data := 'state' + 'not started')`.

Comment: You could also use `in` here: `if f in ('open', 'closed', 'mid', 'not started'): return 'state ' + f`

Comment: Re the update: you could use a dictionary: `funcs = {'open': another_function, 'closed': yet_another_function, ....}` And then `if f in funcs: return (new_data := 'state ' +  funcs[f]())`

Comment: Hmm, using the walrus operator in the way you described still returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It requires 3.8 or better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about using a dictionary. I am going to play around with this idea and see if it works

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I'm working with 3.7 and am not able to upgrade on this project.